# Custom rating bar drawables don't scale

Tags: android

I created a custom rating bar as explained by [kozyr](http://kozyr.zydako.net/2010/05/23/pretty-ratingbar/) and it works great when I have my rating bar set to the exact dimensions of my full and empty drawables (40dp x40dp) but when I attempt to set the size to something smaller the images are not scaled, they are simply cropped.

Is it possible to scale my rating bar without scaling my actual assets?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem as you, since i want my application to run on various different screen resolutions, i want the rating bar to automatically scale according to my needs.

It actually wasn't difficult to create an own class "MyRatingBar" that did exactly what i needed, all the input it requires is:

- a drawable resource int for a "checked" star
- a drawable resource int for an "unChecked" star
- the number of stars you want
- the width you want your rating bar to be
- the height you want your rating bar to be

  ```
  public class MyRatingBar extends RelativeLayout implements OnClickListener {

  private int bitmapChecked;
  private int bitmapUnChecked;
  private byte rating;

  public MyRatingBar(Context context, int bitmapChecked, int bitmapUnChecked, int numSelectors, int ratingBarWidth, int ratingBarHeight) {
  super(context);
  this.bitmapChecked = bitmapChecked;
  this.bitmapUnChecked = bitmapUnChecked;

  int selectorWidth = ratingBarWidth / numSelectors;
  this.rating = -1;

  for (byte i = 0; i < numSelectors; i++) {
      ImageView newSelector = new ImageView(context);
      newSelector.setImageResource(bitmapUnChecked);
      this.addView(newSelector);
      newSelector.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(selectorWidth, ratingBarHeight));
      ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) newSelector.getLayoutParams()).setMargins(selectorWidth * i, 0, 0, 0);
      newSelector.setOnClickListener(this);
  }
  }

  public byte getRating() {
      return this.rating;
  }

  public void setRating(byte rating) {
  this.rating = rating;
  for (int currentChildIndex = 0; currentChildIndex < this.getChildCount(); currentChildIndex++) {
      ImageView currentChild = (ImageView) this.getChildAt(currentChildIndex);
      if (currentChildIndex < rating) {
          currentChild.setImageResource(this.bitmapChecked);
      }
      else {
          currentChild.setImageResource(this.bitmapUnChecked);
      }
  }       
  }

  public void onClick(View clickedView) {
  for (byte currentChildIndex = 0; currentChildIndex < this.getChildCount(); currentChildIndex++) {
      if (this.getChildAt(currentChildIndex).equals(clickedView)) {
          this.setRating((byte) (currentChildIndex + 1));
      }
  }
  }       
  }
  ```